# Wrap search phrases that may start or end with special characters and have common prefixes as whole words only with SPAN tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this code to highlight words that exist in an array everything works fine except it didn't highlight the words that contain '.'

```
spansR[i].innerHTML = t[i].replace(new RegExp(wordsArray.join("|"),'gi'), function(c) {
                return '<span style="color:red">'+c+'</span>';
            });
```

I also tried to escape dot in each word

```
 for(var r=0;r<wordsArray.length;r++){
               if(wordsArray[r].includes('.')){
                 wordsArray[r] = wordsArray[r].replace(".", "\\.");
                  wordsArray[r] = '\\b'+wordsArray[r]+'\\b';
              }
           }
```

I also tried to change replace by those and non of them worked "replace(".", "\.")" , "replace(".", "\.")" , "replace(".", "/.")" , "replace('.','/.')" , "replace('.','/.')" .

This is a simplified test case (I want to match 'free.' )

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var re = "\\bfree\\.\\b";
  var str = "The best things in life are free.";
  var patt = new RegExp(re);
  var res = patt.test(str);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a test case to repro the issue. BTW, `t[i].replace(new RegExp(wordsArray.join("|"),'gi'), function(c) {
                return '<span style="color:red">'+c+'</span>';
            });` should be re-written as `t[i].replace(new RegExp(wordsArray.join("|"),'gi'), '<span style="color:red">$&</span>');`

Comment: WiktorStribiżew : yeah, it's better without the function thanks for that.
mplungjan  : Sorry but I don't need to ignore the '.' I want to highlight each word  in wordsArray that exists in the HTML div. So if wordsArray[r] is firas. I want to highlight every 'firas.' without highlighting 'firas' that's why I can't just delete the '.'

Comment: See the [solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58953968/3832970)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement an unambiguous word boundary in JavaScript.

Here is a version for JS that does not support ECMAScript 2018 and newer:

```js
var t = "Some text... firas and firas. but not firass ... Also, some shop and not shopping";
var wordsArray = ['firas', 'firas.', 'shop'];
wordsArray.sort(function(a, b){
  return b.length - a.length;
});
var regex = new RegExp("(^|\\W)(" + wordsArray.map(function(x) {
  return x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')
}).join("|") + ")(?!\\w)",'gi');
console.log( t.replace(regex, '$1<span style="color:red">$2</span>') );
```

Here, the regex will look like `/(^|\W)(firas\.|firas|shop)(?!\w)/gi`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4sg00q/2). The `(^|\W)` captures into Group 1 (`$1`) start of string or a non-word char, then there is a second capturing group that catures the term in question and `(?!\w)` negative lookahead matches a position that is not immediately followed with a word char.

The `wordsArray.sort` is important, as without it, the shorter words with the same beginning might "win" before the longer ones appear.

The `.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')` is  a must to escape special chars in the search terms.

A variation for JS environments that support lookbehinds:

```js
let t = "Some text... firas and firas. but not firass ... Also, some shop and not shopping";
let wordsArray = ['firas', 'firas.', 'shop'];
wordsArray.sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length );
let regex = new RegExp(String.raw`(?<!\w)(?:${wordsArray.map(x => x.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&')).join("|")})(?!\w)`,'gi');
console.log( t.replace(regex, '<span style="color:red">$&</span>') );
```

The regex will look like `/(?<!\w)(?:firas\.|firas|shop)(?!\w)/gi`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/4sg00q/1). Here, `(?<!\w)` negative lookbehind matches a location that is not immediately preceded with a word char. This also makes capturing group redundant and I replaced it with a non-capturing one, `(?:...)`, and the replacement pattern now contains just one placeholder, `$&`, that inserts the whole match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution:

Replace this:

```
new RegExp(wordsArray.join("|"),'gi')
```

With this:

```
new RegExp(wordsArray.join("|"),'gi').replace(/\./g,'\\.')
```

Example :

```
['javascript', 'firas.', 'regexp'].join("|").replace(/\./g,'\\.')
```

Will print

```
javascript|firas\.|regexp
```

Which is the regular expression you are looking for, with the escaped dot. It will match `firas.` but it will not match `firas`, as you specifically asked in your last comment